# What is the speed of sound in a rigid body?

Tags: energy, waves, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, velocity

A rigid body has particles which never move. So will no sound travel through it ?

Comment: In the limit of an absolutely rigid body, the speed of sound would be infinite.

Comment: @SamuelWeir which is the main reason rigid bodies dont quite work in special relativity :-P

Comment: @user154547 see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rigidity

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I am afraid my abilities are not enough to comprehend what has been proposed. Could you please explain in a layman terms what does it has to do with genral relativity

Comment: @user154547 - He said special relativity, not general (although I suppose that general relativity would be a problem, too). And he was probably just referring to the well known fact that under special relativity nothing can exceed the speed of light (or else a lot of very strange and weird stuff starts happening with causality).

Comment: Rigid bodies, ideal gases, spherical cows, Newtonian mechanics. These are four things that don't exist in reality but that can nonetheless be quite useful as an approximation of reality -- under the right circumstances. Asking about sound in a rigid body is not one of those right circumstances.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no sound inside a rigid body - or rather, the speed of sound is infinite, as disturbances propagate immediately to the whole body.

If that sounds like rigid bodies are a terrible approximation whenever sound is involved, or whenever one needs to take into account the finite propagation speed of disturbances, then you're on the right track.